# How to replace a class in php?

Tags: php, class

I want to replace a class which is loaded in main project by `$addon= new Add_On`; the Add_On class has the structure I like but I want to replace all its details.
I can comment out the `$addon = new Add_on` in main project and load my own , but I don't want to modify the main project's code directly. How can I replace this class?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a new class extending Add_On class:

```
Class Replace_Add_On extends Add_On {
    // Override any functions or add new ones
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, rename the Add_On class to something else, like Base_Add_On, then append this to the file where it is defined:

```
class Add_On extends Base_Add_On
{
    // your custom replacements here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can make change to auto_load or spl_auto_load function in your project ,you will replace these classes with your own.